# Proper way to add an object to an array using concat

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

```
var obj = {name: 'tim', bio: 'lol'};

var arr = [{name: 'beba', bio:'lulu'}, {name: 'keh', bio: 'kih'}];

var newArr = arr.concat([obj]);
or
var newArr = arr.concat(obj);
```

Both concats work but one is with square brackets and the other without them. Are they both correct?

Comment: It's not nice to use two different forms. One for adding arrays into an array and one for adding anything else. It's inconsistent and increases the risk of accidental mistakes.

Comment: `.concat()` is funny... it invokes a spread operator if the provided argument is an array. Sometimes nice, sometimes not so nice.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [docs of concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Yes it is fine. concat function is flexible enough.

> The concat method creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on which it is called, followed in order by, **for each argument, the elements of that argument (if the argument is an array) or the argument itself (if the argument is not an array)**. It does not recurse into nested array arguments.

It internally checks what you are passing and do the things.

```
var new_array = old_array.concat(value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]])
```

Update :

```
var newArr = arr.concat(obj);
```

Means you are passing a single object to concat function.

```
var newArr = arr.concat([obj]);
```

Means you are passing an array  with being a single object in it.

Basically `[]` denotes an array.

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious what do square brackets do in concat? We're not adding an array but an object // Ah, ok, got it. Thanks